# Partitions without 2

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

How do I find the generating function for partitions of $n$ that have no part with size $2$? In general, how would I find this for partitions that have no part of size $k$?

Answer (score 3):

The generating function for $p(n)$ is

$$p(n)=\prod_{k\ge 1}\frac1{1-x^k}=\prod_{k\ge 1}\sum_{j\ge 0}x^{jk}\;:$$

the coefficient of $x^n$ is the number of ways to write $n$ in the form

$$n=j_1\cdot1+j_2\cdot2+j_3\cdot3+\ldots\;.$$

To omit $\ell$ as a summand in the partitions, drop out the factor of $\dfrac1{1-x^\ell}$. Thus, if $p_\ell(n)$ is the desired generating function, you have

$$p_\ell(n)=(1-x^\ell)p(n)\;.$$

Comment: Not as active as before: Even with 50% activity you'd still be one of the more active users. Is less activity due to less interesting questions? Or is it my imagination that there are less interesting questions compared to 3 years ago?

Comment: @Matt: Defense mechanism, to try to avoid getting getting too involved emotionally. I’m not sure about the questions; there may well be fewer interesting ones than when I started, but I’ve not been back long enough to decide whether there’s been much change since I left.

Answer (score 0):

Are objects identical or distinct?

If they are distinct, it may help to think of recursion. Suppose we let S(n, t, r) be the number of partitions of n objects into t partitions out of which r partitions have only 1 object. Then

S(n, t, r) = (t-r)S(n-1, t, r) + S(n-1, t-1, r-1)

This is a similar recursion to Stirling numbers of the second kind, and hope this gets you started.